# How to decide what combinatorics method to use?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, arithmetic, combinations

**Problem:**

> Our football team has 10 members, of which only 3 are strong enough to play offensive lineman, while all other positions can be played by anyone. In how many ways can we choose a starting lineup consisting of a quarterback, a running back, an offensive lineman, and a wide receiver?

Source: [AoPS Alcumus](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/alcumus/problem)

**My Method:**

I first tried the obvious $^3C_1\cdot^9C_3 = 3\cdot84=252$ i.e. choose a lineman from the available three and then the other three team members from the nine left.

But, my answer was wrong and the correct method was to do $3\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7=1512$ which also seems correct, as there are 3 choices for the offensive lineman position, then there are 9 choices for the next position, 8 choices for the position after, and 7 choices for the last position.  Thus, my answer was less by 6 times.

**Question:**

1. How do I decide which method to use?
2. Where did I undercount in my method? It does look well?

Comment: You forget to add the permutations of the other 3 members for each combination, i.e., there are not combinations, they are variations i.e. $9*8*7=\binom{9}{3}*3!=(9)_3$

Comment: @Masacroso Yes. I understood where I was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer assumes that the lineman is distinguishable from the other positions, but that the other three positions are indistinguishable from each other. So, it solves the problem of choosing a lineman and three other players. But these three other players can choose their positions in $3!=6$ ways. Their answer is naturally based off of permutations and directly gets the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation! I can see now where I missed the requirement!